# Html5 canvas, inheritance hierarchy possible cause of flickering?

Tags: javascript, animation, inheritance, canvas, prototype

I'm working on an animated scene in canvas where I have a base class Sprite - all but one object in my project uses single inheritance, as in just inherits from Sprite.

I've got an static animated sprite object inheriting from Sprite, this animated sprite simply moves the clipping region across the sprite sheet. It animated as expected i.e. no flickering when transitioning through the sheet.

However I've got a moving animated sprite, and to save code space i've got this inheriting from AnimatedSprite, so this sprite inherits from an object that inherits from an object.

This new sprite is flickering every frame transition, and i'm wondering if the double inheritance could be causing the issue? As in searching through all three object's prototypes to find function calls?

Sorry that this is a bit lazy in asking without trying, the codebase is fairly large and I won't have time this evening to rewrite the object using the single inheritance model.

So any comments on this would be appreciated!

For the record I am double buffering.

Inheritance function:

```
function __extends(child,parent){ //Global function for inheriting from objects
       function Temp(){this.constructor = child;} //Create a temporary ctor
       Temp.prototype = parent.prototype; 
       child.prototype = new Temp(); //Set the child to an object with the child's ctor with the parents prototype
}
```

Switching frames:

```
SantaSprite.prototype.loopImages = function(){

    if(this.getDirection()){ //If going right set the y frame to the bottom of the sheet
        this.setCurrentFrame(this.getCurrentFrame().getX(),this.getFrameHeight());
    }
    else{ //Else set y to the top of the sheet
        this.setCurrentFrame(this.getCurrentFrame().getX(),0);
    }

    this.setSwitchTime(this.getSwitchTime()+this.getIncrement()); //Increment the timer

    if(this.getSwitchTime() >= this.getSwitchFrame()){ //If the counter has reached the limit

        this.setSwitchTime(0); //Reset the counter

        //Move the frame along one tile in the x axis
        this.setCurrentFrame(this.getCurrentFrame().getX() + this.getFrameWidth());

        //If at the end of x axis, reset back to 0 (left)
        if(this.getCurrentFrame().getX() + this.getFrameWidth() > this.getImage().width){
            this.setCurrentFrame(0,this.getCurrentFrame().getY());
        }
    }

};
```

Cheers

Comment: 1) double buffering is allready implemented for all Browser's canvas, so your game is actually tripple-buffering. I would cancel that in a first debug/prototype phase. 2) Without any code, it's hard to say if your inheritance scheme might be guilty : which inheritance scheme do you use ? Pure js one ? (based on Object.create, apply of the parent constructor, ...) or a lib-based one ? It might also lie in the way you switch frames... hard to say ! Give us some more intel !

Comment: Edited! Is that enough info? Also I took the buffer canvas out and the 'problem' still persists. Thank you for your comment!

Comment: 1) In a first time i would try only in one direction, commenting /* */ the direction change part. 2) anyway, only if currentdirection != previousdirection you should do something. 3) i'm surprised you don't acumulate the error = switchTime-switchFrame, and just erase it (=0). [ Not sure i'm clear here... ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug here was in this line:

```
//Move the frame along one tile in the x axis
    this.setCurrentFrame(this.getCurrentFrame().getX() + this.getFrameWidth()); //No Y value set.
```

The fix:

```
//Move the frame along one tile in the x axis
    this.setCurrentFrame(this.getCurrentFrame().getX() + this.getFrameWidth(),
                         this.getCurrentFrame().getY());
```